# How to align and center 3 divs without affecting middle div

Tags: html, css, django

i am making a game score card, and i want to align 3 divs in same line but the score always stays in the center of the page regardless how long the name of the teams are.

i tried many things but nothing got me results i wanted, if you can help please do, thanks in advance.

```
                    team alpha (logo) 0-0 (logo) team beta
           very long team name (logo) 0-0 (logo) another team
```

---

```
{% for match in matches %}
        <div class="match">
            <div class="home">
                {{match.home_name}} <img src="{{match.home_logo}}">
            </div>
            <div class="score">
                {{match.home_score}} : {{match.away_score}} 
            </div>
            <div class="away">
                <img src="{{match.away_logo}}"> 
                {{match.away_name}}
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are talking about CSS, please share your CSS about it. Or you can check out Flexbox

Answer (score 1):

As Mortiz stated, you can use css flexbox, see example below.

```css
.match {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.score { 
 width: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

.home, .away {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.home {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* not question related */
img {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="match">
    <div class="home">
        Brazil <img src="https://placehold.it/30x30">
    </div>
    <div class="score">
        0 : 1
    </div>
    <div class="away">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/30x30"> 
        The Netherlands
    </div>
</div>

<div class="match">
    <div class="home">
        USA <img src="https://placehold.it/30x30">
    </div>
    <div class="score">
        0 : 1
    </div>
    <div class="away">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/30x30"> 
        Japan
    </div>
</div>

<div class="match">
    <div class="home">
        United Kingdom <img src="https://placehold.it/30x30">
    </div>
    <div class="score">
        2 : 1
    </div>
    <div class="away">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/30x30"> 
        Germany
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flex grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) to achieve this:

```
. match {
  display: flex;
}

.home {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.score {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.away {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```