# Align DIV centrally with content either side

Tags: html, css, styles, center, centering

So I have 5 items (inside a containing DIV). The items lineup as:

Text Image DIV Image Text

I want it displayed so that the DIV is central, the images 'hug' the DIV, then the text 'hugs' the image, so any space left would be on the left or right of the containing DIV.

[How it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej7YT.png)
[How I need it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnRqw.png)

I've used flex to try and attain this, but this just centers the entire content of the containing DIV, rather than the DIV which I want to entirely center.

Comment: It would be helpful to share your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, after an hour more searching I found a thread relating to a very similar requirement which fixed mine.

Solution here - [How to align and center 3 divs without affecting middle div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66187939/how-to-align-and-center-3-divs-without-affecting-middle-div)